# Ocultar filas vacías en tabla con inputs con fórmulas

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una tabla con celdas que obtienen valores con formulas en un script generado a partir de una tabla excel.
En este ejemplo son 4 filas pero el original contiene muchas más,
me gustaría poder ocultar las filas vacías una vez puesto la cantidad y seleccionar el radio elegido, 
Con getElement no lo consigo.este es mi código, Gracias.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>

    </style>

    <script language="javascript">
var co = new Object;
function recalc_onclick(ctl) {
if (true) {
co.pA1C=eeparseFloatV(document.formc.pA1C.value);co.pA2B=document.formc.pA2B.checked;co.pA2C=document.formc.pA2C.checked;calc(co);document.formc.pA5A.value=co.pA5A;document.formc.pA5B.value=co.pA5B;document.formc.pA5C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA5C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA5C):co.pA5C;document.formc.pA5D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA5D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA5D):co.pA5D;document.formc.pA5E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA5E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA5E):co.pA5E;document.formc.pA6A.value=co.pA6A;document.formc.pA6B.value=co.pA6B;document.formc.pA6C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA6C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA6C):co.pA6C;document.formc.pA6D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA6D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA6D):co.pA6D;document.formc.pA6E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA6E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA6E):co.pA6E;document.formc.pA7A.value=co.pA7A;document.formc.pA7B.value=co.pA7B;document.formc.pA7C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA7C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA7C):co.pA7C;document.formc.pA7D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA7D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA7D):co.pA7D;document.formc.pA7E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA7E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA7E):co.pA7E;document.formc.pA8A.value=co.pA8A;document.formc.pA8C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA8C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA8C):co.pA8C;document.formc.pA8D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA8D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA8D):co.pA8D;document.formc.pA8E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA8E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA8E):co.pA8E;
};};
var eeisus=0;var eetrue="VERDADERO";var eefalse="FALSO";var eedec=",";var eeth=".";var eedecreg=new RegExp(",","g");var eethreg=new RegExp("[.]","g");
var eecm1=new Array();function calc(data){var cA1C=data.pA1C;var cA2B=data.pA2B;var cA2C=data.pA2C;var tmp55=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp56=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt57_sum=((true&&tmp56)&&tmp55);var sumcnt57_cnt=2;var cA5A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt57_sum,sumcnt57_cnt,eecm1))?("c1"):("")));var tmp52=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp53=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt54_sum=((true&&tmp53)&&tmp52);var sumcnt54_cnt=2;var cA5B=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt54_sum,sumcnt54_cnt,eecm1))?(""):("")));var tmp49=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp50=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt51_sum=((true&&tmp50)&&tmp49);var sumcnt51_cnt=2;var cA5C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt51_sum,sumcnt51_cnt,eecm1))?(((cA1C=="")?0:cA1C)):("")));var tmp46=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp47=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt48_sum=((true&&tmp47)&&tmp46);var sumcnt48_cnt=2;var cA5D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt48_sum,sumcnt48_cnt,eecm1))?(5):("")));var tmp43=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp44=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt45_sum=((true&&tmp44)&&tmp43);var sumcnt45_cnt=2;var cA5E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt45_sum,sumcnt45_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA5D))*(v2n(cA5C)))):("")));var tmp40=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp41=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt42_sum=((true&&tmp41)&&tmp40);var sumcnt42_cnt=2;var cA6A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt42_sum,sumcnt42_cnt,eecm1))?("c2"):("")));var tmp37=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp38=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt39_sum=((true&&tmp38)&&tmp37);var sumcnt39_cnt=2;var cA6B=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt39_sum,sumcnt39_cnt,eecm1))?("R2"):("")));var tmp34=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp35=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt36_sum=((true&&tmp35)&&tmp34);var sumcnt36_cnt=2;var cA6C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt36_sum,sumcnt36_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA1C))/(2))):("")));var tmp31=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp32=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt33_sum=((true&&tmp32)&&tmp31);var sumcnt33_cnt=2;var cA6D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt33_sum,sumcnt33_cnt,eecm1))?(2):("")));var tmp28=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp29=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt30_sum=((true&&tmp29)&&tmp28);var sumcnt30_cnt=2;var cA6E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt30_sum,sumcnt30_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA6D))*(v2n(cA6C)))):("")));var tmp25=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp26=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt27_sum=((true&&tmp26)&&tmp25);var sumcnt27_cnt=2;var cA7A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt27_sum,sumcnt27_cnt,eecm1))?("c3"):("")));var tmp22=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp23=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt24_sum=((true&&tmp23)&&tmp22);var sumcnt24_cnt=2;var cA7B=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt24_sum,sumcnt24_cnt,eecm1))?("R3"):("")));var tmp19=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp20=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt21_sum=((true&&tmp20)&&tmp19);var sumcnt21_cnt=2;var cA7C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt21_sum,sumcnt21_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA1C))*(2))):("")));var tmp16=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp17=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt18_sum=((true&&tmp17)&&tmp16);var sumcnt18_cnt=2;var cA7D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt18_sum,sumcnt18_cnt,eecm1))?(4):("")));var tmp13=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp14=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt15_sum=((true&&tmp14)&&tmp13);var sumcnt15_cnt=2;var cA7E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt15_sum,sumcnt15_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA7D))*(v2n(cA7C)))):("")));var tmp10=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp11=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt12_sum=((true&&tmp11)&&tmp10);var sumcnt12_cnt=2;var cA8A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt12_sum,sumcnt12_cnt,eecm1))?("c4"):("")));var tmp7=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp8=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt9_sum=((true&&tmp8)&&tmp7);var sumcnt9_cnt=2;var cA8C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt9_sum,sumcnt9_cnt,eecm1))?(((cA1C=="")?0:cA1C)):("")));var tmp4=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp5=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt6_sum=((true&&tmp5)&&tmp4);var sumcnt6_cnt=2;var cA8D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt6_sum,sumcnt6_cnt,eecm1))?(1):("")));var tmp1=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp2=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt3_sum=((true&&tmp2)&&tmp1);var sumcnt3_cnt=2;var cA8E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt3_sum,sumcnt3_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA8D))*(v2n(cA8C)))):("")));data.pA5A=cA5A;data.pA5B=cA5B;data.pA5C=cA5C;data.pA5D=cA5D;data.pA5E=cA5E;data.pA6A=cA6A;data.pA6B=cA6B;data.pA6C=cA6C;data.pA6D=cA6D;data.pA6E=cA6E;data.pA7A=cA7A;data.pA7B=cA7B;data.pA7C=cA7C;data.pA7D=cA7D;data.pA7E=cA7E;data.pA8A=cA8A;data.pA8C=cA8C;data.pA8D=cA8D;data.pA8E=cA8E;};
function str_ne(x,y){return(x.toLowerCase()!=y.toLowerCase())};function var_ne(x,y){var xt=mytypeof(x);var yt=mytypeof(y);if(xt!=yt)return true;switch(xt){case 1:case 3:return(x!=y);case 2:return str_ne(x,y);default:return true}};function mytypeof(v){switch(typeof v){case "number":if(myIsNaN(v))return 4;return 1;case "string":return 2;case "boolean":return 3;case "object":if(v.constructor==Number){if(myIsNaN(v))return 4;return 1;};if(v.constructor==String){return 2;};if(v.constructor==Boolean){return 3;};return 4;default:return 4;}};function myIsNaN(x){return(isNaN(x)||(typeof x=='number'&&!isFinite(x)));};function andgeneral(cnt,vsum,vcnt,x){if(!vsum){return false;};for(var ii=0;ii<x.length;ii++){var arr=x[ii][0];for(var jj=x[ii][1];jj<=x[ii][3];jj++){for(var kk=x[ii][2];kk<=x[ii][4];kk++){if(!arr[jj][kk]){return false;};};};};return true;};function s2n(str){str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");return parseFloat(str);}function b2s(b){return b?eetrue:eefalse;};function v2n(v){switch(typeof v){case "number":return v;case "string":return s2n(v);case "boolean":return v?1:0;case "object":if(v.constructor==Number){return v;};if(v.constructor==String){return s2n(v);};if(v.constructor==Boolean){return v?1:0;};return Number.NaN;default:return Number.NaN;}};function eedisplayFloat(x){if(myIsNaN(x)){return Number.NaN;}else{return String(x).replace(/\./g,eedec);}};function eedisplayFloatV(x){if(x=="")return x;if(isFinite(x)){return String(x).replace(/\./g,eedec);}else{return x}};var eeparseFloatVreg=new RegExp("^ *-?[0-9.]+ *$");function eeparseFloatV(str){if(str=="")return str;str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");if(!eeparseFloatVreg.test(str)){return str;};var res=parseFloat(str);if(isNaN(res)){return str;}else{return res;}};function eeisstring(v){switch(typeof v){case "string":return true;case "object":return v.constructor==String;default:return false;}};function eeisnumber(v){if(isNaN(v)||v==Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY||v==Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY){return false;}else{switch(typeof v){case "number":return true;case "object":return v.constructor==Number;default:return false;}}};
  </script>

    <title>prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="formc" name="formc" method="post"
    action="">
    <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cantidad de conjuntos </td>
        <td>
        <input name="pA1C" id="pA1C" value="" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloatV(eeparseFloatV(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA1C')"
     tabindex="1"
     style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
     type="text"></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Modelo</td>
        <td>
        <input name="m" id="pA2B"
     onclick="recalc_onclick('pA2B')" tabindex="2"
     type="radio"></td>
        <td>
        <input name="m" id="pA2C"
    onclick="recalc_onclick('pA2C')" tabindex="3"
    type="radio"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 296pt;"
    bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" bordercolor="#666666"
    cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="394">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 15pt;" 
    align="right" height="20">Código
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
    Ref interna
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
    Unidades
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
    Precio €
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
    Total €
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 15pt;" 
     align="right" height="20"><input name="pA5A"
     id="pA5A" value="" readonly="true"
     style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
      type="text">
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA5B" id="pA5B" value=""
     readonly="true"
     style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
     type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA5C" id="pA5C" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA5D" id="pA5D" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA5E" id="pA5E" value=""
     readonly="true"
     style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
     type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 15pt;" 
    align="right" height="20"><input name="pA6A"
    id="pA6A" value="" readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text">
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA6B" id="pA6B" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA6C" id="pA6C" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA6D" id="pA6D" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
     type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA6E" id="pA6E" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 15pt;" 
    align="right" height="20"><input name="pA7A"
    id="pA7A" value="" readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text">
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA7B" id="pA7B" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA7C" id="pA7C" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA7D" id="pA7D" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA7E" id="pA7E" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 15pt;" 
    align="right" height="20"><input name="pA8A"
    id="pA8A" value="" readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text">
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
    &nbsp; </td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA8C" id="pA8C" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA8D" id="pA8D" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA8E" id="pA8E" value=""
    readonly="true"
    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
    type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script language="javascript">
    recalc_onclick('');
    </script>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

http://llevant.com/prueba/pruebafilas.html

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: organiza la pregunta, muestra que has intentado... el código tiene mucho desorden

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser en javascript puro o te has planteado utilizar algún framework como jQuery?

Comment: Hola, la verdad es que conozco muy poco tanto jQyery como JS, aunque siempre pensé que jQuery era una librería JS, pero la verdad es que puedo usar lo que me digais para resolver el problema que llevo días buscando y no encuentro. Modificare las etiquetas. Jorge, ahora pruebo tu sugerencia, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>

    <style>

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var co = new Object;
    function recalc_onclick(ctl) {
        if (ctl) {
            co.pA1C=eeparseFloatV(document.formc.pA1C.value);co.pA2B=document.formc.pA2B.checked;co.pA2C=document.formc.pA2C.checked;calc(co);document.formc.pA5A.value=co.pA5A;document.formc.pA5B.value=co.pA5B;document.formc.pA5C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA5C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA5C):co.pA5C;document.formc.pA5D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA5D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA5D):co.pA5D;document.formc.pA5E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA5E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA5E):co.pA5E;document.formc.pA6A.value=co.pA6A;document.formc.pA6B.value=co.pA6B;document.formc.pA6C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA6C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA6C):co.pA6C;document.formc.pA6D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA6D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA6D):co.pA6D;document.formc.pA6E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA6E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA6E):co.pA6E;document.formc.pA7A.value=co.pA7A;document.formc.pA7B.value=co.pA7B;document.formc.pA7C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA7C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA7C):co.pA7C;document.formc.pA7D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA7D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA7D):co.pA7D;document.formc.pA7E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA7E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA7E):co.pA7E;document.formc.pA8A.value=co.pA8A;document.formc.pA8C.value=eeisnumber(co.pA8C)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA8C):co.pA8C;document.formc.pA8D.value=eeisnumber(co.pA8D)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA8D):co.pA8D;document.formc.pA8E.value=eeisnumber(co.pA8E)?eedisplayFloat(co.pA8E):co.pA8E;

            $("table#table tr").show();
            var isNull = 0;
            $("table#table tr input").each(function(i,input){
                var total = $(input).closest("tr").find("input").length;
                if($(input).val()==""){
                    isNull++;
                }
                if(isNull==total){
                    $(input).closest("tr").hide();
                    isNull = 0;
                }

            });
        };



    };



    var eeisus=0;var eetrue="VERDADERO";var eefalse="FALSO";var eedec=",";var eeth=".";var eedecreg=new RegExp(",","g");var eethreg=new RegExp("[.]","g");
    var eecm1=new Array();function calc(data){var cA1C=data.pA1C;var cA2B=data.pA2B;var cA2C=data.pA2C;var tmp55=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp56=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt57_sum=((true&&tmp56)&&tmp55);var sumcnt57_cnt=2;var cA5A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt57_sum,sumcnt57_cnt,eecm1))?("c1"):("")));var tmp52=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp53=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt54_sum=((true&&tmp53)&&tmp52);var sumcnt54_cnt=2;var cA5B=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt54_sum,sumcnt54_cnt,eecm1))?(""):("")));var tmp49=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp50=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt51_sum=((true&&tmp50)&&tmp49);var sumcnt51_cnt=2;var cA5C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt51_sum,sumcnt51_cnt,eecm1))?(((cA1C=="")?0:cA1C)):("")));var tmp46=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp47=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt48_sum=((true&&tmp47)&&tmp46);var sumcnt48_cnt=2;var cA5D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt48_sum,sumcnt48_cnt,eecm1))?(5):("")));var tmp43=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp44=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt45_sum=((true&&tmp44)&&tmp43);var sumcnt45_cnt=2;var cA5E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt45_sum,sumcnt45_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA5D))*(v2n(cA5C)))):("")));var tmp40=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp41=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt42_sum=((true&&tmp41)&&tmp40);var sumcnt42_cnt=2;var cA6A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt42_sum,sumcnt42_cnt,eecm1))?("c2"):("")));var tmp37=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp38=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt39_sum=((true&&tmp38)&&tmp37);var sumcnt39_cnt=2;var cA6B=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt39_sum,sumcnt39_cnt,eecm1))?("R2"):("")));var tmp34=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp35=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt36_sum=((true&&tmp35)&&tmp34);var sumcnt36_cnt=2;var cA6C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt36_sum,sumcnt36_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA1C))/(2))):("")));var tmp31=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp32=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt33_sum=((true&&tmp32)&&tmp31);var sumcnt33_cnt=2;var cA6D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt33_sum,sumcnt33_cnt,eecm1))?(2):("")));var tmp28=(((cA2B)==(true)));var tmp29=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt30_sum=((true&&tmp29)&&tmp28);var sumcnt30_cnt=2;var cA6E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt30_sum,sumcnt30_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA6D))*(v2n(cA6C)))):("")));var tmp25=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp26=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt27_sum=((true&&tmp26)&&tmp25);var sumcnt27_cnt=2;var cA7A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt27_sum,sumcnt27_cnt,eecm1))?("c3"):("")));var tmp22=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp23=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt24_sum=((true&&tmp23)&&tmp22);var sumcnt24_cnt=2;var cA7B=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt24_sum,sumcnt24_cnt,eecm1))?("R3"):("")));var tmp19=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp20=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt21_sum=((true&&tmp20)&&tmp19);var sumcnt21_cnt=2;var cA7C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt21_sum,sumcnt21_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA1C))*(2))):("")));var tmp16=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp17=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt18_sum=((true&&tmp17)&&tmp16);var sumcnt18_cnt=2;var cA7D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt18_sum,sumcnt18_cnt,eecm1))?(4):("")));var tmp13=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp14=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt15_sum=((true&&tmp14)&&tmp13);var sumcnt15_cnt=2;var cA7E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt15_sum,sumcnt15_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA7D))*(v2n(cA7C)))):("")));var tmp10=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp11=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt12_sum=((true&&tmp11)&&tmp10);var sumcnt12_cnt=2;var cA8A=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt12_sum,sumcnt12_cnt,eecm1))?("c4"):("")));var tmp7=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp8=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt9_sum=((true&&tmp8)&&tmp7);var sumcnt9_cnt=2;var cA8C=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt9_sum,sumcnt9_cnt,eecm1))?(((cA1C=="")?0:cA1C)):("")));var tmp4=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp5=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt6_sum=((true&&tmp5)&&tmp4);var sumcnt6_cnt=2;var cA8D=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt6_sum,sumcnt6_cnt,eecm1))?(1):("")));var tmp1=(((cA2C)==(true)));var tmp2=(var_ne((cA1C),("")));var sumcnt3_sum=((true&&tmp2)&&tmp1);var sumcnt3_cnt=2;var cA8E=(((andgeneral(0,sumcnt3_sum,sumcnt3_cnt,eecm1))?(((v2n(cA8D))*(v2n(cA8C)))):("")));data.pA5A=cA5A;data.pA5B=cA5B;data.pA5C=cA5C;data.pA5D=cA5D;data.pA5E=cA5E;data.pA6A=cA6A;data.pA6B=cA6B;data.pA6C=cA6C;data.pA6D=cA6D;data.pA6E=cA6E;data.pA7A=cA7A;data.pA7B=cA7B;data.pA7C=cA7C;data.pA7D=cA7D;data.pA7E=cA7E;data.pA8A=cA8A;data.pA8C=cA8C;data.pA8D=cA8D;data.pA8E=cA8E;};
    function str_ne(x,y){return(x.toLowerCase()!=y.toLowerCase())};function var_ne(x,y){var xt=mytypeof(x);var yt=mytypeof(y);if(xt!=yt)return true;switch(xt){case 1:case 3:return(x!=y);case 2:return str_ne(x,y);default:return true}};function mytypeof(v){switch(typeof v){case "number":if(myIsNaN(v))return 4;return 1;case "string":return 2;case "boolean":return 3;case "object":if(v.constructor==Number){if(myIsNaN(v))return 4;return 1;};if(v.constructor==String){return 2;};if(v.constructor==Boolean){return 3;};return 4;default:return 4;}};function myIsNaN(x){return(isNaN(x)||(typeof x=='number'&&!isFinite(x)));};function andgeneral(cnt,vsum,vcnt,x){if(!vsum){return false;};for(var ii=0;ii<x.length;ii++){var arr=x[ii][0];for(var jj=x[ii][1];jj<=x[ii][3];jj++){for(var kk=x[ii][2];kk<=x[ii][4];kk++){if(!arr[jj][kk]){return false;};};};};return true;};function s2n(str){str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");return parseFloat(str);}function b2s(b){return b?eetrue:eefalse;};function v2n(v){switch(typeof v){case "number":return v;case "string":return s2n(v);case "boolean":return v?1:0;case "object":if(v.constructor==Number){return v;};if(v.constructor==String){return s2n(v);};if(v.constructor==Boolean){return v?1:0;};return Number.NaN;default:return Number.NaN;}};function eedisplayFloat(x){if(myIsNaN(x)){return Number.NaN;}else{return String(x).replace(/\./g,eedec);}};function eedisplayFloatV(x){if(x=="")return x;if(isFinite(x)){return String(x).replace(/\./g,eedec);}else{return x}};var eeparseFloatVreg=new RegExp("^ *-?[0-9.]+ *$");function eeparseFloatV(str){if(str=="")return str;str=String(str).replace(eedecreg,".");if(!eeparseFloatVreg.test(str)){return str;};var res=parseFloat(str);if(isNaN(res)){return str;}else{return res;}};function eeisstring(v){switch(typeof v){case "string":return true;case "object":return v.constructor==String;default:return false;}};function eeisnumber(v){if(isNaN(v)||v==Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY||v==Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY){return false;}else{switch(typeof v){case "number":return true;case "object":return v.constructor==Number;default:return false;}}};
</script>

<title>prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formc" name="formc" method="post"
    action="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Cantidad de conjuntos </td>
            <td>
                <input name="pA1C" id="pA1C" value="" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloatV(eeparseFloatV(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA1C')"
                tabindex="1"
                style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Modelo</td>
            <td>
                <input name="m" id="pA2B"
                onclick="recalc_onclick('pA2B')" tabindex="2"
                type="radio"></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="m" id="pA2C"
                    onclick="recalc_onclick('pA2C')" tabindex="3"
                    type="radio"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table id="table" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 296pt;"
        bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" bordercolor="#666666"
        cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="394">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="height: 15pt;" 
            align="right" height="20">Código
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
            Ref interna
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
            Unidades
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
            Precio €
        </td>
        <td  align="right">
            Total €
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 15pt;" 
        align="right" height="20"><input name="pA5A"
        id="pA5A" value="" readonly="true"
        style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
        type="text">
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
        <input name="pA5B" id="pA5B" value=""
        readonly="true"
        style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
        type="text"></td>
        <td  align="right">
            <input name="pA5C" id="pA5C" value=""
            readonly="true"
            style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
            type="text"></td>
            <td  align="right">
                <input name="pA5D" id="pA5D" value=""
                readonly="true"
                style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                type="text"></td>
                <td  align="right">
                    <input name="pA5E" id="pA5E" value=""
                    readonly="true"
                    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                    type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 15pt;" 
                    align="right" height="20"><input name="pA6A"
                    id="pA6A" value="" readonly="true"
                    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                    type="text">
                </td>
                <td  align="right">
                    <input name="pA6B" id="pA6B" value=""
                    readonly="true"
                    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                    type="text"></td>
                    <td  align="right">
                        <input name="pA6C" id="pA6C" value=""
                        readonly="true"
                        style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                        type="text"></td>
                        <td  align="right">
                            <input name="pA6D" id="pA6D" value=""
                            readonly="true"
                            style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                            type="text"></td>
                            <td  align="right">
                                <input name="pA6E" id="pA6E" value=""
                                readonly="true"
                                style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                type="text"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="height: 15pt;" 
                                align="right" height="20"><input name="pA7A"
                                id="pA7A" value="" readonly="true"
                                style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                type="text">
                            </td>
                            <td  align="right">
                                <input name="pA7B" id="pA7B" value=""
                                readonly="true"
                                style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                type="text"></td>
                                <td  align="right">
                                    <input name="pA7C" id="pA7C" value=""
                                    readonly="true"
                                    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                    type="text"></td>
                                    <td  align="right">
                                        <input name="pA7D" id="pA7D" value=""
                                        readonly="true"
                                        style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                        type="text"></td>
                                        <td  align="right">
                                            <input name="pA7E" id="pA7E" value=""
                                            readonly="true"
                                            style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                            type="text"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="height: 15pt;" 
                                            align="right" height="20"><input name="pA8A"
                                            id="pA8A" value="" readonly="true"
                                            style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                            type="text">
                                        </td>
                                        <td  align="right">
                                        &nbsp; </td>
                                        <td  align="right">
                                            <input name="pA8C" id="pA8C" value=""
                                            readonly="true"
                                            style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                            type="text"></td>
                                            <td  align="right">
                                                <input name="pA8D" id="pA8D" value=""
                                                readonly="true"
                                                style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                                type="text"></td>
                                                <td  align="right">
                                                    <input name="pA8E" id="pA8E" value=""
                                                    readonly="true"
                                                    style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
                                                    type="text"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

                                    </form>
                                </body>
                                </html>
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, deberias esperar a que el OP responda al comentario de @Kiko_L sobre si quiere usar jQuery o no. En estos momentos la pregunta solo tiene la etiqueta de `javascript` y el OP no ha confirmado si es posible responder con jQuery por lo que tu respuesta no es valida en estos momentos.

Comment: Hola Jorge, he añadido en el head el jQuery y el código al final de la función, pero no hace nada, o no lo sé hacer...

Comment: estoy en ello, veo que la tabla muestra los values de los input como texto y no texto en si, por eso no te funciona, ya lo tengo hecho pero tengo que saber poner el codigo en la parte exacta dentro de todo lo q tienes.

Comment: te actualizo el codigo en unos segundos, ahora funciona

Comment: Buenos días, y disculpa la tardanza, este fin de semana he implementado el código en el documento original en una tabla de unas 300 filas, y funciona perfecto (con algunos retoques en la maquetación del html) muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Me pregunto cual función podría utilizar para imprimir esa tabla reducida y mandarla por mail, (tengo una empanada mental de vértigo de todo lo que leo por las webs) no quisiera abusar de tu paciencia. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Pues tendrías que poner un botón que al dar click primero te borre los <tr> que tenga display:none, y después hacer un loop de todos los <tr> y guardar el value del input en un array y enviarlo por ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Mira con esta función puede ocultar las filas que quieras

`<script>
function ocultarFilasVacias(){
            var tabla = document.getElementById('bodyFilas');
            for(var i = 1;i < tabla.children.length;i++){
                if(tabla.children[i].children[0].children[0].value == '' && tabla.children[i].children[2].children[0].value == '' && tabla.children[i].children[3].children[0].value == ''  && tabla.children[i].children[4].children[0].value == ''){
                    tabla.children[i].hidden = true;
                }else{
                    tabla.children[i].hidden = false;
                }
            }
        }
</script>`

ahora te explico debes ponerle al  de la tabla donde esán las filas calculadas id="bodyFilas" ahora yo compruebo si los  que tienen hijos  tienen value '' y oculto la fila completa es decir el  ahora si lo que quieres es ejecutar la función cuando marques radio debes llamarla en el evento onclick y si quieres que se ejecute cunado cambie en el  donde pones el valor debes llamarla en los eventos onkeyup y onblur, mira te dejo parte del código aquí

```
<body>
<form id="formc" name="formc" method="post"
action="">
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Cantidad de conjuntos </td>
    <td>
    <input name="pA1C" id="pA1C" value="" onkeyup="this.value=eedisplayFloatV(eeparseFloatV(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA1C');ocultarFilasVacias();" onblur="this.value=eedisplayFloatV(eeparseFloatV(this.value));recalc_onclick('pA1C');ocultarFilasVacias();"
 tabindex="1"
 style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
 type="text"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Modelo</td>
    <td>
    <input name="m" id="pA2B"
 onclick="recalc_onclick('pA2B');ocultarFilasVacias();" tabindex="2"
 type="radio"></td>
    <td>
    <input name="m" id="pA2C"
onclick="recalc_onclick('pA2C');ocultarFilasVacias();" tabindex="3"
type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 296pt;"
bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" bordercolor="#666666"
cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="394">
<tbody id="bodyFilas">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 15pt;" 
align="right" height="20">Código
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
Ref interna
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
Unidades
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
Precio €
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
Total €
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 15pt;" 
 align="right" height="20"><input name="pA5A"
 id="pA5A" value="" readonly="true"
 style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
  type="text">
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA5B" id="pA5B" value=""
 readonly="true"
 style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
 type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA5C" id="pA5C" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA5D" id="pA5D" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA5E" id="pA5E" value=""
 readonly="true"
 style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
 type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 15pt;" 
align="right" height="20"><input name="pA6A"
id="pA6A" value="" readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text">
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA6B" id="pA6B" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA6C" id="pA6C" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA6D" id="pA6D" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
 type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA6E" id="pA6E" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 15pt;" 
align="right" height="20"><input name="pA7A"
id="pA7A" value="" readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text">
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA7B" id="pA7B" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA7C" id="pA7C" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA7D" id="pA7D" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA7E" id="pA7E" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 15pt;" 
align="right" height="20"><input name="pA8A"
id="pA8A" value="" readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text">
    </td>
    <td  align="right">
&nbsp; </td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA8C" id="pA8C" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA8D" id="pA8D" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
    <td  align="right">
    <input name="pA8E" id="pA8E" value=""
readonly="true"
style="border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 62pt;" size="11"
type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script language="javascript">
recalc_onclick('');
</script>
</form>
<script>
    function ocultarFilasVacias(){
        var tabla = document.getElementById('bodyFilas');
        for(var i = 1;i < tabla.children.length;i++){
            if(tabla.children[i].children[0].children[0].value == '' && tabla.children[i].children[2].children[0].value == '' && tabla.children[i].children[3].children[0].value == ''  && tabla.children[i].children[4].children[0].value == ''){
                tabla.children[i].hidden = true;
            }else{
                tabla.children[i].hidden = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola, mejora la redacción de tu respuesta por favor, no se ve nada bien. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. El documento original lleva una tabla de unas 300 filas, ¿el id del tr debería ser el mismo para todas? o sea id="bodyFilas" ?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. El documento original lleva una tabla de unas 300 filas, ¿el id del tr debería ser el mismo para todas? o sea id="bodyFilas" ?. Por otra parte la celda no esta vacia, contiene un input cuyo campo si puede estar vacio o no, por ese motivo creo que las funciones con "getElementById" no ocultan.

Comment: Hola Gulliem, el id debes ponerselo al tbody de la tabla donde guardas los datos disculpa si no te espliqué bien, no debes ponerselo a los tr, y si yo voy al value del input q es el hijo del td, ese es el que valido q esté vacío

Comment: Mira Guillem edité mi respuesta y te puse como quedó el body de tu página html después de mi edición revísala y pruébala para que veas como funciona

Comment: Hola, las disculpas son mías por lo novato que soy, jeje. Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias de verdad, he visto que llamas a la función con un "onkeyup" y "onblur" en el primer input, quizás en el original lo ponga en los "radios". Una vez filtrado los vacios, ¿como podria imprimir la tabla y mandarla por mail? ¿es complicado?

Comment: Guillem si te sirvió te agradecería que me puntuaras para ver si subo de reputación, gracias